# Plotly graph doesn't show up in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-python

I am following the tutorial provided by *plotly.com*. But for the very first examples I encountered issues.
[image]

[image]

I tried using `.Figure` and `.FigureWidget` respectively and they both didn't work, leaving a blank canvas.

I've also checked renderer configuration, just like this:

```
-----------------------
    Default renderer: 'plotly_mimetype+notebook'
    Available renderers:
        ['plotly_mimetype', 'jupyterlab', 'nteract', 'vscode',
         'notebook', 'notebook_connected', 'kaggle', 'azure', 'colab',
         'cocalc', 'databricks', 'json', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'svg',
         'pdf', 'browser', 'firefox', 'chrome', 'chromium', 'iframe',
         'iframe_connected', 'sphinx_gallery', 'sphinx_gallery_png']
```

When I changed the renderer to 'browser', the plot could be displayed properly on another tab in Chrome. But I still expect a way to get it displayed right in my jupyter notebook.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

---

Now I open my notebook with Jupyter Notebook instead of Jupyterlab and re-run the kernel, the plot works well! But still wonder why Jupyterlab doesn't work...

Comment: I have jupyterlab 3.0.16 in my environment and I can see the graph. What is the version you are currently using?

Comment: @r-beginners Mine is 3.0.14, no big difference I guess?

Comment: The modules that jupyterlab requires are listed below, so are any of them outdated? `ipython, jupyterlab-server, nbclassic, packaging, jinja2, jupyter-server, tornado, jupyter-core` For example, nbclassic, ipython, etc.

Comment: @r-beginners Modules you listed are up-to-date in my jupyterlab environment. All packages I could update now, according to my anaconda navigator, are ```hdf5, icu, idna, jedi, parso, sip, zeromq```.

Comment: Finally, is ipywidgets>=7.6 or higher? I referred to [here](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support).

Comment: @r-beginners I've also read that documentation and mine is 7.6.3. I installed it today so it's probably the latest version.

Comment: How did you install it? `conda`, `pip`, sth else? Also, open Dev Tools in your browser and show us the error message.

Answer (score 3):

You must use the `iframe` renderer:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'iframe'
```

Result:
[image: Code and result]